# Why is there a difference in speed of forward and reverse traffic over 10 G network in iperf tool

Tags: network-speed, 10gbethernet, iperf

I have a 10G network setup between my two servers (say, Server1 and Server2) and I'm using `iperf` tool to measure the bandwidth of the network.
Here are test cases that I performed,

**Test Case 1: (Forward Data Transfer)**

Making `Server 1` as `iperf server` and `Server 2` as `iperf client`.

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4] 0.0-10.0 sec   8.81 GBytes  7.56 Gbits/sec
```

**Test Case 2: (Reverse Data Transfer)**

Making `Server 2` as `iperf server` and `Server 1` as `iperf client`.

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4] 0.0-10.1 sec  1.05 GBytes   893 Mbits/sec
```

Moreover, I've the same configuration on both servers.

**OS:** `Redhat 7.4`

**MTU:** `9000 bytes`

**10G network card information** (*via ethtool*) on both server are also same.

```
Settings for em2:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: umbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

**Network Switch:**  `SG350XG-2F10 12-Port 10G Stackable Managed Switch`

Here's the network connectivity diagram for better understanding.

[image: Network Connectivity Diagram]

Can anyone suggest why there is a difference in speeds of the forward vs the reverse traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the cause.  What version of iperf are you running on both the client and server.  iperf -v should provide this.

Can you try [iperf 2.0.14a](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/) after a fresh compile?  Note, this code is still under development. This may or may not help answer your question.

Bob

Comment: I am using `iperf version 2.0.8 (6 Mar 2015) pthreads` on Server 1 and `iperf version 2.0.12 (25 June 2018) pthreads` on Server 2.

Comment: I'd suggest 2.0.13 on both.   Also the output with -e on both might be helpful.